# How do I hide content on specific page using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, post, widget

I need to hide a post widget, below css isn't working??

```
body .postid-6074 .widget_its-single- 
post { 
display: none; 
}
```

Comment: without more of your code example, we cannot reproduce your error....that said....some possible explanations are that your selector isn't finding the object to apply the css ....or what I suspect is more likely....is that css is getting overwritten by another css rule that gets applied later.....view your page in a browser using developer tools and review the css rules to see what is getting applied and from where

Answer (score -1):

you can add a class in the body tag that represents that page

```
body.page-name .postid-6074 .widget_its-single- 
post { 
display: none; 
}
```

like this, It will solve your problem